# pandas Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df:

```
      MinMaleTA

0    888(G2M)
1    888(AAM)
2    888(G2M)
3    888(G2M)
4    456
5    123
```

I want to add a new column:

if the df['MinMaleTA'] contains string "( )",the value of the new column will be the string inside the "( )".

if the df['MinMaleTA'] doesn't contains string "( )",the value of new column will be None.

The output should looks like:

```
      MinMaleTA   NewCol

0    888(G2M)     G2M
1    888(AAM)     AAM
2    888(G2M)     G2M
3    888(G2M)     G2M
4    456          None
5    123          None
```

I tried:

```
df['ScaleName']=np.where(df['MinMaleTA'].str.contains("(",regex=False),df['MinMaleTx'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)'),None)
```

Error:

```
 Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1
```

And I tested:

```
df['MinMaleTA'].str.contains("(",regex=False)
```

Output is:

```
True
True
True
True
False
False
```

and:

```
df['MinMaleTx'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')
```

Output is:

```
G2M
AAM
G2M
G2M
None
None
```

So it seams :

Both:

```
 df['MinMaleTA'].str.contains("(",regex=False)
```

and

```
df['MinMaleTx'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')
```

works ,they will do their job.

But once I combine them together into:

```
df['ScaleName']=np.where(df['MinMaleTA'].str.contains("(",regex=False),df['MinMaleTx'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)'),None)
```

error comes out:

```
Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1
```

Comment: What's wrong with your last approach `df['MinMaleTx'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')`?

Comment: What's this `Tx` column and how is it different from `TA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error has to do with the broadcasting rules related to `str.extract`.

When you run `df['MinMaleTA'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')`, you don't get a `pd.Series`, you get a `pd.DataFrame` with columns ranging from 0 to your N number of capture groups. Because you only have one capture group, this appears like this:

```
     0
0  G2M
1  AAM
2  G2M
3  G2M
4  NaN
5  NaN
```

What this means is that when you make your `np.where` selector, it passes for each row, this whole data frame. Thus:

```
>>> np.where(df['MinMaleTA'].str.contains("(",regex=False),
             df['MinMaleTA'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)'), np.nan)
array([['G2M', 'G2M', 'G2M', 'G2M', nan, nan],
       ['AAM', 'AAM', 'AAM', 'AAM', nan, nan],
       ['G2M', 'G2M', 'G2M', 'G2M', nan, nan],
       ['G2M', 'G2M', 'G2M', 'G2M', nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]], dtype=object)
# Nb I substituted `np.nan` for `None`
```

This is why you have 6 entries rather than 1. To solve this, in your `where` statement, append `.iloc[:, 0]` to `str.extract`.

---

Alternatively, from an answer merged into here by Anurag Dabas, pass `expand=False` to `str.extract`. Since you are only capturing a single group, this will return the series that `np.where` expects. Thus:

```
df['ScaleName']=np.where(
    df['MinMaleTA'].str.contains("(",regex=False),
    df['MinMaleTA'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)',expand=False),
    None)
```

Note that this does not work if there is more than one capture group: `str.extract` returns data frame in such cases.

Comment: sounds good! Can you put the code in your answer?

Comment: Literally just append `.iloc[:, 0]` to your `str.extract` call... `df['MinMaleTA'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)').iloc[:, 0]`. The point of this is to select the first column out of the resulting data frame with the capture groups.

Comment: I did received an 0 at the top of the column it looks weird.

Comment: Thank you so much it works ,but @Anurage Dabas method is simpler. Thank you all the same.

Comment: The other method isn't robust to multiple capture groups because it changes the return type based on whether it's 1 or 2 dimensional. Avoiding that inconsistency is why `str.extract` has the default return type `DataFrame` and why `expand` has default argument `True`. Hiding that with a keyword argument, while convenient, is obfuscatory magic.

Comment: I don't think there's any "right" or "better" way here; it simply has to do with programming preferences

Comment: @ifly6 sir If you don't mind can I edit your answer?

Comment: Well I guess that depends on what changes you want to make

Comment: @ifly6 you can rollback changes if you don't like it **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas thanks, just cleaned up a bit of the language to make it flow consistently; if you want to make any future clarifications, feel free to; I also added your name into the answer explicitly